# Integral extensions of rings, when one of the rings is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

The following is from page 61 of *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah & Macdonald:

> **Proposition 5.7.** Let $A\subseteq B$ be integral domains, $B$ is integral
>   over $A$. Then $B$ is a field if and only if $A$ is a field.

I am curious what happens if we drop the hypothesis of "integral domains". It will probably be false (since the hypothesis plays a role in the proof). Thus my question is:

> What would be example of $A\subseteq B$ commutative rings such that
>   $B$ is integral over $A$ and
>
> a) $A$ is a field, but $B$ is not a field.
>
> b) $B$ is a field, but $A$ is not a field.

Let me say a word about a). I think the situation a) is actually impossible. Because it seems to me that in the proof of this  direction, only $A$ being integral domain is used. Thus, if $A$ is a field (in particular integral domain), then $B$ must also be a field. **Edit:** As Ted shows, I was wrong. The situation (a) is possible.

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: (a) is possible.  See answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $A \subset B$ and $B$ is a field, then $A$ must at least be an integral domain (subrings of fields are integral domains).  So (b) is impossible.

(a) is possible, though.  For example, if $A$ is a field then $B = A[x]/(x^2)$ is a ring which is a finitely generated $A$-module and therefore integral over $A$.  But $B$ is not a field.

Comment: Oh how silly me! Thanks! (+1) I see you have edited your answer. So "integral domain" condition is still necessary.